# Camera app on iPhone 4 suddenly deletes the sound of 5 previous videos and all future ones!

Tags: iphone, microphone, sound-volume, camera-roll

I use an iPhone 4 to record videos with the Camera App. Suddenly, the 5 most recent videos got muted sound for no reason at all. The rest of the Camera Roll still has audio. Just those 5 videos got their sound deleted.

I record a new video, and it also has no sound. Why did that happen? I know this isn't caused by dust in the tiny microphone hole by the headphone jack. That would only make future recordings have no sound.

I record a video and shout into the microphone. I play-back the video at maximum volume, and zero audio comes out. That's how I know it's not a problem with the microphone.

Comment: Just to cover bases, I suggest importing the videos onto a computer or tablet to see if the problem persists there. The goal would be to isolate the video file and confirm that it is the file being corrupted.

Comment: What version of iOS do you have, just wondering? Also have you tried this with other 3rd party camera and video apps? I'd recommend trying. Have you tried playing video from the Photos app too? Have you tried putting the videos on another computer to see if it really does have sound?